# Nodemailer works on my localhost but not on my remote server

Tags: node.js, express, server, local, nodemailer

I have this problem with nodemailer, which works fine on my localhost, but when I pull it on my remote server it doesn't works, giving me CONNTIMEOUT error. Why does this happens? Pratically, nodemailer doesn't create the transporter for my message which I define in successive part of my code

```
   const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    const smtpPool = require('nodemailer-smtp-pool')    

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpPool({
        service: "Gmail",
        port: 587,
        auth: {
            user: 'myuser@gmail.com',
            pass: 'mypass'
        },
        connectionTimeout: 10000,
        socketTimeout: 10000
    }));

    transporter.verify(function(error,success) {
        if(error) {
            res.send(error);
        } else {
            res.send("Server is ready to take our messages");
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing-

1. [Enable less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4No9DhhWyidTlcIt0EeiJrmDlanXEd-j7LtWgT2Zx_ETD-6eOVlbA-bYCJ680Dq1Ktv6fqUbkGh2I1uOmKu5y3_WAhhcw)
2. [Disabel captcha](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha)
3. Changin port to port: 465.

Check for all this and it should work.